# convert number string into float with specific precision (without getting rounding errors)

Tags: matlab, floating-point

I have a vector of cells (say, size of `50x1`, called `tokens`) , each of which is a struct with properties `x`,`f1`,`f2` which are strings representing numbers. for example, `tokens{15}` gives:

```
x: "-1.4343429"
f1: "15.7947111"
f2: "-5.8196158"
```

and I am trying to put those numbers into 3 vectors (each is also `50x1`) whose type is `float`. So I create 3 vectors:

```
x = zeros(50,1,'single');
f1 = zeros(50,1,'single');
f2 = zeros(50,1,'single');
```

and that works fine (why wouldn't it?). But then when I try to populate those vectors: (`L` is a `for` loop index)

```
x(L)=tokens{L}.x;
.. also for the other 2
```

I get :

> The following error occurred converting from string to single:
>   Conversion to single from string is not possible.

Which I can understand; implicit conversion doesn't work for `single`. It does work if `x`, `f1` and `f2` are of type `50x1 double`.

The reason I am doing it with floats is because the data I get is from a C program which writes the some floats into a file to be read by matlab. If I try to convert the values into doubles in the C program I get rounding errors...

So, (after what I hope is a good question,) **how might I be able to get the numbers in those strings, at the right precision?** (all the strings have the same number of decimal places: 7).

The MCVE:

```
filedata = fopen('fname1.txt','rt'); 
%fname1.txt is created by a C program. I am quite sure that the problem isn't there.
scanned = textscan(filedata,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
raw = scanned{1};
stringValues = strings(50,1);
for K=1:length(raw)
    stringValues(K)=raw{K};
end
clear K %purely for convenience

regex = 'x=(?<x>[\-\.0-9]*),f1=(?<f1>[\-\.0-9]*),f2=(?<f2>[\-\.0-9]*)';
tokens = regexp(stringValues,regex,'names');

x = zeros(50,1,'single');
f1 = zeros(50,1,'single');
f2 = zeros(50,1,'single');

for L=1:length(tokens)
    x(L)=tokens{L}.x;
    f1(L)=tokens{L}.f1;
    f2(L)=tokens{L}.f2;
end
```

Comment: I am legit scared to post this, but here goes.

Comment: I did not follow all of that, but note that converting between binary radix and denary radix will cause additional rounding errors. On top of the precision of the two representations. E.g. $0.\dot{3}$ ≈ 0.333333 ≈ 0.010101010 ≈ 0.33203125

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor not sure I see how that's relevant.

Comment: May not be “I did not follow all of that, but …”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use function `str2double` before assigning into yours arrays (and then cast it to single if you want). Strings (char arrays) must be explicitely converted to numbers before using them as numbers.

Comment: not sure I understand how that works. Could you give an example or some explanation?

Comment: `x(L)=single(str2double(tokens{L}.x));`

Comment: @Bentoy13 correct, but note that `single(str2double(x))` is subject to double rounding and could be 1ulp off the nearest single precision floating point to x... A pity that Matlab does not provide a str2single...

Comment: @aka.nice Totally agree. I don't understand the point of having `str2num` and `str2double`, and no `str2num(class)`. I don't see how to avoid potential  rounding here.